# Loading animation doesn't show up until after ajax call completes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Possible duplicate: [Same problem (unresolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535373/loading-animation-doesnt-show-up-until-after-ajax-call-completes-in-safari-chro)

I show loading DOM before the Ajax call and after the Ajax call, I hide it. For some reason, the loading image appears only after ajax call completes. The result is that the loading image doesn't even appear unless I put `delay(#).hide(0)` The code is the following:

```
$("#loading-popup").show();
$.ajax({
// ajax here
});
$("#loading-popup").hide(0);
```

I have tested on other Ajax calls on my website and the same problem occurs. Has anyone got this resolved? I am using Chrome 26.

EDIT: I forgot to specify that I am using **synchronous** ajax call. (`async: false`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on whether the ajax call is synchronous or asynchronous.

For **asynchronous** ajax call, the following works:

```
$("#loading-popup").show();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
// other parameters
success: function(yourdata)
{
    $("#loading-popup").hide();
}
```

For **synchronous** ajax call, it does **NOT**. Ajax gets executed first and all other processes are blocked/queued.

A way around it is to use setTimeOut like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
$("#loading-popup").show();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
async: false,
// other parameters
//
// other codes
});
$("#loading-popup").hide();
}, 10);
```

But because it is synchronous, the loading GIF will NOT animate and just become a static image (At least for Chrome that is)

I guess there are only two solutions:
1) use asynchronous ajax call
2) use static loading image

Answer (score 0):

The [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is `async` function and the statements under it might execute before the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call is completed. You have to hide in `success` or `done` function.

```
$("#loading-popup").show();
$.ajax({
// ajax here
}).success(data){
   $("#loading-popup").hide(0);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You pointed me in the right direction in terms of research. I decided to post a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know Im a bit late to the party on this, but for future reference if you want to have a loading animation AND use a synchronous ajax call AND have it animate in chrome, you can use this third party ajax script: http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/#!

> Spin.js dynamically creates spinning activity indicators that can be
>   used as resolution-independent replacement for AJAX loading GIFs.

I use it extensively and it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way.

```
var $ani = $('#loading-popup').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $ani.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $ani.hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this problem is already resolved, but try this:

```
$("#loading-popup").show();
$.ajax({
// ajax here
success: function(data) {
  $("#loading-popup").hide();
}
});
```

let me know if this works..