# Show a popup div when talking to AJAX server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, popup

I'm trying to show a popup in the middle of the screen while my website talks to my AJAX server. Since some of the operations take a couple seconds to do, I want to give my users a visual cue that an operation is occurring. For example, you can create a music playlist on my site. When the playlist is being created, I want a div to popup saying it's creating the playlist on my servers.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDNXc/547/) to show the functions I'm using to try to produce this, but I'm having a bit of an opposite effect. In the fiddle, it shows the popup after it tries to talk to the server (it will fail to talk to the server because I deny anything outside my domain), but since it fails to talk to the sever, it never calls `hide_popup()`.

On my servers, it never even shows the popup (unless I call an `alert()` directly after the `show_popup()` call).

I'm not sure why this happens, but I simply want to
 1. Show the popup
 2. Execute my AJAX-call
 3. Hide the popup

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using async = false. This stackoverflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000803/loading-animation-doesnt-show-up-until-after-ajax-call-completes) might help you.

Comment: Your jsfiddle example doesn't work, because you are doing cross domain  request. This is also probably reason, why do you have oposite effect. You got Uncaught Error: NetworkError: DOM Exception 19 which stops javascript so popup can't be hidden. Anyway, I think that your approach to this problem is correct.

Comment: @Windkiller the approach is actually incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the way you wrote your code. Here are a couple of them:

(1.) *Call*:

`var response = get_server_response("action=createPlaylist&name=" + name, false);`

You are expecting a response immediately which will not happen with an AJAX call. Moreover, you are passing `false` for the `async` parameter, which is making it effectively a `sync` call. This is why your code is just waiting before doing anything else.

(2.) *Implementation*:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", ajax_server, async);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(url);
return response;
```

You are only caching the result in `response` and not processing it while tracking `onreadystatechange`. You are actually processing it just after the call which will execute after the call and not on receiving the response. No need to return the response here.

(3.) *popup*:

You are not using show/hide at an appropriate place.

**Solution**:

I would suggest you fire a callback while tracking the `onreadystatechange` by implementing a function. Show the popup just before you make the network call. Hide it inside your callback function depending on the `readyState` and `status`.

Here is a working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nDNXc/549/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I think he wants to make call synchronous. You shouldnt for example allow visitors to load another playlist while the first one isnt loaded yet...

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to use a common library for your Ajax calls, e.g. [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Second learn about asynchronous Javascript. Your call of get_server_response() returns immediately without waiting for your Ajax request to complete. Have a look at the complete parameter in jQuery.ajax. It accepts a function that is called when your requests completes - the right place to hide your message!

Comment: My call of `get_server_response()` shouldn't return immediately because I made a variable called 'async' and set it to false. This makes it wait until it is done sending before returning a value.

Comment: He made call synchronous. So javascript is stunned till call is resolved. But it flush error, thats why it doesnt work. His approach is correct.