# Ajax loading animation not animated during first call

Tags: css, ajax, animated-gif

I would like to display the following animated GIF to the user while an Ajax call is made:

[image]

The GIF appears as expected and for the duration of the call, but is not animated during the first call. On subsequent calls it is animated, making it seem as if the browser is slow at caching the animation of the GIF.

**jQuery:**

```
$body = $("body");
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() {
    $body.addClass("loading");
  },
  ajaxStop: function() {
    $body.removeClass("loading");
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal1 {
  display:    none;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )
  url(../images/loader.gif)
  50% 50%
  no-repeat;
}

body.loading {
 overflow: hidden;
}

body.loading .modal1 {
  display: block;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000803/loading-animation-doesnt-show-up-until-after-ajax-call-completes) question covered animations appearing after the Ajax call and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978909/gif-loader-image-does-not-animate-during-ajax-call) question's answer doesn't fit with my implementation.

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your browsers developer tools. It can give some information about the loading of assets. A possible workaround would be to load the image initially but hide it, and only show it when you want it.

Comment: its probably not fully loaded the first time.  You can load it somewhere else on the page that is hidden if you want to implement this way.