# Loader gif freezing in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Im using a loader gif image in an mvc application in such a way that when an ajax call is made the loader shows until it is completed. Loader works perfectly fine in chrome and Firefox bt in the case of ie gif image is loaded bt when the ajax call is made it freeze until it is completed.

Sample code

```
Showloader(show) ;
SetTimeout(sleep(), 300) ;
Showloader(hide) ;
```

Why this is happening in IE only ? is that a browser issue ?

Comment: if  you set `async: false` of your ajax call , it will freeze your UI

Comment: Yes async is false. But it is working in all other browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16000803/842112

Comment: can you add your Ajax code in the question

Comment: Not work for me. Still the gif freeze

Comment: I also have the same issue in IE where I tried both sync true and false

Comment: Set async:true, it's resolve this issue.
[best choice for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000803/loading-animation-doesnt-show-up-until-after-ajax-call-completes)